# UICollectionView: invalidatelayout while keyboard is showing

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a simple UICollectionView for which I've so far had no reason to subclass UICollectionViewLayout.

The problem is I've introduced a textfield, and while the keyboard is showing on the UICollectionView,

```
collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
```

**does nothing at all**, which means I can no longer resize sections on rotation.

I believe I would have to override the **shouldInvalidateLayoutForBounds** method of a custom UICollectionViewLayout subclass, but that seems excessive given my use case.  Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here ?

Comment: I think I want to know if there's a way to invalidate the collectionView layout while the keyboard is showing, without having to subclass collectionViewLayout.